# How to generate a slug for documents that already exist in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql, slug

My MongoDB database is very large (about 10 million items using 1000 MB of disk space), but it's documents do not have a slug based on the title. Currently a document looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "630f3c32c1a580642a9ff4a0"
  },
  "title": "This is a title",
  "Post": "this is a post"
}
```

But I want it like this

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "630f3c32c1a580642a9ff4a0"
  },
  "title": "This is a title",
  "slug": "this-is-a-title",
  "Post": "this is a post"
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example of your expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$replaceAll` and `$toLower` inside an update pipeline for this:

```
db.collection.update(
  {},
  [{$set: {
      slug: {
        $replaceAll: {
          input: {$toLower: "$title"},
          find: " ",
          replacement: "-"
        }
      }
  }}],
  {multi: true}
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5vs1xIEOISI)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting `TypeError: <collection-name>.update is not a function` when I tried the accepted answer on mongodb 5.1.0, so I did it using the below code.

```
const products = db.collection("Products");

await products.updateMany({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      slug: {
        "$replaceAll": {
          input: {
            $toLower: "$name"
          },
          find: " ",
          replacement: "-"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

replace `$name` with the property of which you want to create slug.
Also, don't forget to replace the collection name with yours ;D